# To add JFields to the tabs: Menu Assignment & Module Permissions which fieldset name do i need to use?

Tags: joomla

For better understanding about the question please check the link "Joomla backend" below that what i am asking? [Joomla backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RYoc.png)

Comment: This question has already been answered for you: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/16780/168

Answer (score 0):

You can't add your custom JField for the tabs - menu Assignment and Menu Permissions due to core feature of Joomla- Yet you have three options for that as below:

1. For the module tabs use

   ```
       <fieldset name="basic">
   ```
2. For the Advanced tab use

   ```
   <fieldset name="advanced">
   ```
3. For the Custom tab Use

   ```
   <fieldset name="custom_name">
   ```